# How to make the conversion from 'int' to 'char' reasonable under -Werror=conversion option? c++11

Tags: c++, algorithm, char, integer, c++17

`error: conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ may change value [-Werror=conversion]`

build cmd example:
`g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o a.out -Werror=conversion`

```
    auto index = 3;
    char singleChar = 'A' + index; // I want to get A-Z
```

I hope sigleChar is dynamically assigned.
could you pls help me to solve this error report without using switch?
How would it be better to write code?

Comment: `char singleChar = static_cast<char>('A' + index);`

Comment: You're assuming that uppercase letters are a contiguous set of values (`'B' == 'A' + 1`, `'C' == 'B' + 1`, etc).   The C++ standard guarantees no such thing - and there are real-world standardised character sets for which that isn't true.   It might be simpler to do `char singleChar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[index]` or (due to commutativity of pointer arithmetic) `index["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'A' + index; // I want to get A-Z` would only works for ASCII, not EBCDIC for example.

A more portable solution (and not int to char conversion involved) is array indexing:

```cpp
char singleChar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[index];
```

Comment: Hi, Jarodr42, That's looks good!  But I have another question, could you pls help me?

If I can't control the value of index. How can I write code more appropriately if index larger then 25?

Comment: Not sure what you expect for out of bound value? `index % 26` might ensure you are in bound.

Comment: Thank you !        if index was come from a string. How do I make sure the index is within range?  Or should I report an error?   std::string name="my12"; // could be "myxx"
        auto size    = name.size();
        auto index   = std::stoi(name.substr(2, size));
        char singleChar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[index%26];

Comment: Error handling is up to you. Possibly, `if (index < 0 || 26 <= index) throw std::out_of_range("!")`.

Comment: `index%26` would not be in bounds if `index` is negative.

Answer (score 0):

You have to typecast it to a `char`:

```
auto index = 3;
char singleChar {static_cast<char>('A' + index)};
```

Comment: That's really nice!

Comment: Hi, If I want to save as function, should I add try-catch ?     char fun(int index){

    try{
        char singleChar = static_cast<char>('A' + index);
    }    
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() <<"\n";
    }
    return singleChar;
    
}

Comment: @Mr.Zhang This expression in the `try` block will never throw an exception. The exception handling is totally unnecessary.

Comment: I mean if fun(256)